# Edit text with alert dialog box

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am new to android development and I want to show an alert dialog box for an edit text field. User should enter his weight from 10kg to 99kg only if he enters more than 2 digits  alert dialog box should appear, and also  with out entering the weight if we press the measure Button it should show the alert dialog. plz some one help me with sample code.

The alert dialog should contain both text and OK button. Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Weight");
alertDialog.setMessage("You forgot to enter your weight!");
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // do something when the user presses OK (place focus on weight input?)
   }
});
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

See this: [Alert Dialog Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText eText = (EditText)findViewById(----id of the editText---);
Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(----id of the button);
AlertDialog aDialog = new AlertDialog(context);
aDialog.setTitle("Alert!!!");
aDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Ok","");

okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
String weightString = eText.getText();
if(weightString.equals("")||weightString == null)
{
aDialog.setMessage("You forgot to enter your weight");
aDialog.show();
}
else if(Integer.parseInt(weightString)>99)
{
aDialog.setMessage("Enter a weight less than 100");
aDialog.show();
}
}
});
```